# Android Chat app, update the chat when you receive a new message

Tags: android, android-activity, chat, refresh

I am new in the Android development but a Java programmer.

I am using a database and REST services to run a Chat app,
but I don't know how to update my app if the app receives a new message.

In the activity I send a JSON request to receive all the messages from chat during the creation of the activity.

But how to update my view when I receive a message from notification or another method...

Maybe there is a way to use the firebase notification service to update my view?

Thanks for answering
Champ

Answer (score 0):

You can regularly check for new messages using a [timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer)

for example, every second, check for a new message:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //retrieve your message in here
    }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer I don't think this is the best solution for a chat application.
I think I can use this kind of service to update my chat app https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/432d3b72b8c058f220416958b444274ddd186abd/LocationUpdatesForegroundService

What do you think?

Comment: This is of course a bad solution ! But if your service doesn't notify you that there is new data, that's fine. It is preferable in this case to use a [firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start), it is a real-time database and it will notify you as soon as the data is available.

Comment: Thanks,
I am using the FCM to send notification when someone sends a message and updating the UI with the FirebaseMessagingService using BroadcastReceiver.